# function merging / combinator in fsharp

Tags: f#, functional-programming, combinators

I have a list of functions accepting the same type as an input, different types as output

```
 [ f_i :  Mytype -> res:Sometype_i ]
```

Which operation can merge them into one function of the following type ?

```
 f : Mytype -> \Product_i Mytype_i
```

Identically, if I have a list of functions returning the same type

```
 [ f_i : Mytype_i -> res:Sometype ]
```

Which operation can merge them into one function of the following type ?

```
 f : \Product_i Mytype_i ->  Mytype list
```

It would be some canonical "preCombinator" or "postCombinator".
(I imagine it has a name in FP..)

Comment: I dont understand what you mean - your syntax is not F# - in particular `func` is not a F# keyword, also idiomatically F# writes `int list` rather than `[int]` which is confusing (I think this is what you mean)

Comment: sorry i am not too familiar with fsharp syntax. I guess you have to remove the func in order to what fsahrp outputs as type. I will edit it.

Comment: if you use F# interactive it will print out the type signatures for you which can help in questions like this, you can also use the `--sigfile` option if you use the compiler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your first question is that you cannot do that in general. A list is a data structure with dynamic length, but the length of the resulting tuple has to be known statically at compile time. (You could construct the resulting tuple using reflection and use it as `obj`, but that's not really useful.)

In the second case, you want to turn a list of functions into a function returning list, which can be done (both have dynamic length). You can write something like:

```
let funcs =
  [ (fun n -> n + 1)
    (fun n -> n * 2) ]

let merged =
  funcs |> List.fold (fun agg f ->
    fun inp -> (f inp)::(agg inp)) (fun _ -> [])
```

The primitive operation (passed to `fold`) is a function that takes a function of type `TInp -> TOut list` and a function `TInp -> TOut` and combines them into a function returning a longer list. So you could also write:

```
// val addResult : ('a -> 'b list) -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b list  
let addResult agg f inp = (f inp)::(agg inp)

// val merge : ('a -> 'b) list -> ('a -> 'b list)
let merge funcs = funcs |> List.fold addResult (fun _ -> [])
```

Comment: yes I figured out I could write it myself, but I thought there would be some builtin combinators. at least it is very pedagogical !

Comment: very true, the type itself is changing. it would be possible only by going to untyped 'obj' world... interestingly I am already thrown into it at this point, because I went into reflection to create setter for my record fields automatically. now if I want to create a setter for my entire structure from the individual fields setter, I cant do it statically. This is the same problem that I have seen many, many times, of mixing. The reflection world breaks the types.

Comment: This is because reflection is from a higher 'runtime level' and we are using runtime "level -1" in the type environement of runtime "level 0". Type Provider solve that thing nicely : we can express the problem, which is inherently "level -1" as we want dynamic maps, but we run it to provide "level 0" with types, and this level does mix type generation from its own level, which is "level -1", with usage of such types, which is "level 0"

Comment: Again, this is a problem I have seen many, many times. (and I am convinced the solution goes through this runtime level idea but that's another thing)

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to Tomas' solution for the second problem with the added bonus of returning the functions in the same order as they were initially

```
let funcs =
  [ (fun n -> n + 1)
    (fun n -> n * 2) ]

let merged = fun input -> funcs |> List.map (fun f -> f input)
```